# fading between images with attr src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below,but I don't get the pictures to be fade and replace

I see the I'm getting on the firebug console :

"missing ) after argument list"
and also when I click on the function changeBg the console say that "changeBg is not defined"

```
   JS:
<script language="JavaScript">
function changeBg (color) {$("#mainimg1).attr("src",Images/"+color+".jpg).fadeIn(3000)};
</script>
    HTML
    <img id="mainimg1" src="Images/black.jpg">
   <img src="Images/blue.png" onclick="changeBg(this.name);" name="blue">
            <img src="Images/fuksia.png" onclick="changeBg(this.name);" name="fuksia">
            <img src="Images/brown.png" onclick="changeBg(this.name);" name="brown">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten a `"`, unbalancing the statement

```
function changeBg (color) {$("#mainimg1).attr("src",Images/"+color+".jpg).fadeIn(3000)};
                                       ^--- missing " here              ^--and here (thanks Johnny)
```

Comment: ok,now I'm getting on the console that: Images is not defined

Comment: @Johnny: Ah yes, good eye. Thanks. Adding that to the answer.

Comment: @Liran: I'd suggest using a syntax-highlighting editor for this. You'd have seen the "wrong" colors on this line with one.

Comment: Hi Marc,I'm am using syntax-highlinghing :)

Comment: ok,I remove /Images/ totally now,but I'm getting this:$("#mainimg1").attr("src", "+color+".jpg").fadeIn is not a function